# Phone unique identifier discrepancy

Tags: android, uuid

A while ago I was looking for a way to uniquely identify a device my application was running on.  I found the following algorithm:

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) baseContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

final String tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
final String tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
final String androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(baseContext.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
return deviceUuid.toString();
```

Can anyone explain to me why this would occasionally be giving me differing results on the same device, and what I can do to correct it?

Comment: Do remember that many Android devices don't have a SIM! e.g. Google TV, many tablets, media players, etc

Comment: That's fine.  That section will just end up being empty.  What I'm asking is why the same device would all of the sudden produce a different result.

Comment: May be this is not an answer to this question, but google recently published guidelines for having a unique identifier as opposed to using the getDeviceId method. You would want to take a look at it here : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: This is excellent advantej.  Could you please post this in an answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advantej and Ollie C both posted the answer to this question.  Have a look at the following page:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem relates to getSimSerialNumber() as that is getting the serial number for one specific SIM card, so if the owner of the phone changes the SIM (e.g. by moving network) the method will return a different ID. The SIM is unique, but each device may use different SIMs at different times.

Comment: Yea, I can see how this would be a problem.  This isn't the problem I'm running into because my device's SIM has not been swapped, but you do make a good point.  Can you think of any other possible reasons?

Comment: The docs say that ANDROID_ID "should" remain the same for the life of the device, so that'd be my second target. The DeviceId is usually the IMEI and that won't change. I wonder whether if the phone ius hardware reset or flashed that the ANDROID_ID would change. That method seems overkill to me, I'm not sure why it's better than just using the IMEI number or equivalent, but perhaps there are some types of phones where it's not unique.

Comment: Interesting... I wonder if upgrading one's Android version could cause this to happen.  What do you think?  I mean who knows what Samsung or Motorola or anyone does with their alterations to Android.  Maybe they update (if they can) the Android ID for some reason?

Comment: That use of the word "should" is quite telling to me, and says that under some (unspecified) circumstances, it WILL change. For GSM phones the IMEI is enough to uniquely identify a phone, but I am not sure whether the equivalent for CDMA is unique.

Comment: Do have a look at this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html